# How to fix EF Core migration "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Connection String:

```
Data Source=<server>,<port>;Initial Catalog=<database>;User Id=<username>;
Password=<password>?;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=false;Integrated Security=false;Trusted_Connection=true;
Connection Timeout=30;
```

My connection string contains:

```
TrustServerCertificate=false
```

and I get this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

When I have a connection string with this:

```
TrustServerCertificate=true
```

I get:

> Login failed for user '<username>'. // <-- real username removed

Comment: It's weird to have `Integrated Security=false;Trusted_Connection=true`. These tokens are synonyms. The last one wins.

Answer (score 26):

The EF Core 7.0 breaking changes addresses this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes

> There are three ways to proceed:
>
> 1. Install a valid certificate on the server. Note that this is an
>    involved process and requires a obtaining a certificate and ensuring
>    it is signed by an authority trusted by the client.
> 2. If the server has a certificate, but it is not trusted by the
>    client, thenTrustServerCertificate=True to allow bypassing the normal
>    trust mechanims.
> 3. Explicitly add Encrypt=False to the connection string.

Comment: I have added, Encrypt=False, and still the same issue with EF 7.0

Comment: Adding TrustServerCertificate=true worked for me.

Comment: Adding `Encrypt=False` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and solve it by adding `Encrypt=False` into connection string.

Then I checked your connection string I think by changing Encrypt value to False instead of true it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I received same error when try a  "Scaffold" command into a Nuget Console. The version Of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer was 7.0.0.
Then I downgrade this two package to the 6.0.9 version and all works fine.

Comment: This happened to me, too. Reverting to 6.0.9 temporarily resolved. It seems to be related to .net 7.